# Microsoft Access 2016: Conditional Inner Join Multiple Cases

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, switch-statement

I hope what I'm asking for makes sense. I would like to have a query that chooses a specific type of Inner Join based on a user input.

This is what I have.

Queries:

- qryFiltered (Main Query)
- qryLand (sub)
- qrySea (sub)
- qryAllOrder (sub)

Tables:

- tblLowPriority

Forms:

- EnterWork (which has a option group called ogLandSea)

In my main query "qryFiltered", I have the following SQL code:

```html
SELECT qryAllOrder.*

FROM
SWITCH
(Forms!EnterWork!ogLandSea = 1, (qryAllOrder LEFT JOIN tblLowPriority ON qryAllOrder.[WORK_ORDER_NBR] = tblLowPriority.[WO]) INNER JOIN qrySea ON qryAllOrder.WORK_ORDER_NBR = qrySea.WORK_ORDER_NBR,

Forms!EnterWork!ogLandSea = 2, (qryAllOrder LEFT JOIN tblLowPriority ON qryAllOrder.[WORK_ORDER_NBR] = tblLowPriority.[WO]) INNER JOIN qryLand ON qryAllOrder.WORK_ORDER_NBR = qryLand.WORK_ORDER_NBR)

WHERE tblLowPriority.WO Is Null
```

Basically, what I'm looking for is to choose the join based on what the user selects on the form. The inner join would choose either qrySea or qryLand based on this input. The error I'm getting is: "Syntax error in FROM clause."

What am I doing wrong here? It's the Switch function that's not working. I tried the two Land and Sea options separately without the Switch function and it works. I just can't seem to figure out a way to have the Inner Join change based on user input.

Appreciate all your responses!

Comment: that syntax is not supported. there are probably other ways to produce the results you desire but for that you need to share more details on the table(s), structure, data in the tables,  definition of your queries . maybe easier to post your database somewhere.

Comment: Build one query and one report and apply filter criteria to report according to user choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing a Left Join from the main query to the two subqueries. And then I put a Switch criteria in the WHERE Clause:

```js
WHERE (Switch([Forms]![EnterWork]![ogLandSea]=1,[qrySea]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Not Null Or [qrySea]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Null Or [qryLand]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Not Null,[Forms]![EnterWork]![ogLandSea]=2,[qrySea]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Not Null,[Forms]![EnterWork]![ogLandSea]=3,[qryLand]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Not Null,[Forms]![EnterWork]![ogFN]=4,[qrySea]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Null And [qryLand]![WORK_ORDER_NBR] Is Null))<>False)
```

Basically, this is what it does:

- Option 1: Display all records from the Main Query
- Option 2: Display only records that are in qrySea
- Option 3: Display only records that are in qryLand
- Option 4: Display only records that are NOT in qrySea nor qryLand